# Loop through dataframe and add text to a cell in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment, line-breaks, string-concatenation

Using the ToothGrowth dataset in R as an example, I used `ToothGrowth$comment <- "Comment 1"` to create a Comment column with this format:

```
   len supp dose comment
1  4.2   VC  0.5  Comment 1
2 11.5   VC  0.5  Comment 1
3  7.3   VC  0.5  Comment 1
```

I want to loop through each row and add more comments, so that the final dataframe looks something like this:

```
   len supp dose comment
1  4.2   VC  0.5  Comment 1
                  
                  Comment 2
                  Meow
2 11.5   VC  0.5  Comment 1

                  Comment 2
                  Meow

3  7.3   VC  0.5  Comment 1
                  
                  Comment 2
                  Meow
```

So far, I have tried these 3 things:

```
for i in 1:nrow(ToothGrowth):
  newcom <- paste("Comment 2", "Meow", sep="\n")
  addnewcom <- paste(ToothGrowth$comment[i], newcom, sep="\n", col="\n")
  ToothGrowth$comment[i] <- addnewcom

for i in 1:nrow(ToothGrowth):
  newcom <- paste("Comment 2", "Meow", sep="\n")
  addnewcom <- paste(ToothGrowth$comment[i], cat(newcom[1]), sep="\n", col="\n")
  ToothGrowth$comment[i] <- cat(addnewcom[1])

for i in 1:nrow(ToothGrowth):
  newcom <- capture.outcome(cat(paste("Comment 2", "Meow", sep="\n")))
  addnewcom <- capture.outcome(cat(paste(ToothGrowth$comment[i], newcom, sep="\n", col="\n")))  
  ToothGrowth$comment[i] <- addnewcom
```

I've been able to get "Comment1\n\nComment2\nMeow" to output, but I'm struggling to get the actual line breaks to output.

Thank you!

Comment: I‘m not entirely sire what‘s your ultimate goal? Do you just want to add the same comment described in your example to every row? Or will there be some logic that will add different (!) comments based on other column values?

Comment: Because currently it simply looks like the comment you want to add should have line breaks.

Comment: `ToothGrowth$comment <- "Comment 1\n\nComment 2\nMeow"`? or as 2nd step,  `ToothGrowth$comment <- paste0(ToothGrowth$comment, "\n\nComment 2\nMeow"`)?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to add a blank line, Comment # on a new line and the actual comment on another line. There's no logical or condition. For my actual data, I'm combing the content of two columns, but for sake of simplicity, I just want to add "\n\nComment 2 \n Meow" in the example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly, then it would be

```
ToothGrowth$comment <- "Comment 1"
ToothGrowth$comment <- paste(ToothGrowth$comment, "\n", "Comment 2", "Meow", sep = "\n")

# Example of result: comment from first row
cat(ToothGrowth[1, ]$comment)
# Comment 1
#
#
# Comment 2
# Meow
```

In R, it is often best to avoid loops if you are doing exactly the same thing to each row. Vector operations are usually much, much faster.

Comment: This seems correct, but when I view the final dataframe, it shows "Comment1\n\nComment2\nMeow" instead of the actual new lines. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: That is correct. That is what the string looks like. I've edited my answer to clarify this by printing it out with the cat() function.